# NFS service is not found

Tags: nfs, services

I unable to start nfs service

```
# systemctl start nfs-server
Failed to start nfs-server.service: Unit is masked.
# service nfs status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status nfs.service
Unit nfs.service could not be found.
```

Both RPC and NFS are installed, I noticed there no file in:

```
# cd /lib/systemd/system/nfs-common.service
bash: cd: /lib/systemd/system/nfs-common.service: No such file or directory
```

System info:

```
Static hostname: cimnfsclient 
Icon name: computer-vm 
Chassis: vm 
Machine ID: 4f241c5567164542ad656857ca51ee58 Boot ID: 19f292b5bef4418eae63e0c1fb995cbb 
Virtualization: vmware 
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) CPE 
OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7 
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64 
Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: It's really difficult to answer any question if you tell nothing of your setup, at least the distro and version. Does [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/failed-to-start-nfs-service-unit-nfs-service-not-found-4175677090/) help?

Comment: Static hostname: cimnfsclient
Icon name: computer-vm
Chassis: vm
Machine ID: 4f241c5567164542ad656857ca51ee58
Boot ID: 19f292b5bef4418eae63e0c1fb995cbb
Virtualization: vmware
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64

I also checked if the NFS or RPC install , they were install but i am getting this error and i would like to resolve this issue today

Comment: Please put that [into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/669061/edit). Here in the comments it's very easy to miss

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
root@cimnfsclient rajan]# systemctl start nfs-server
Failed to start nfs-server.service: Unit is masked.
```

This means someone has previously used `systemctl mask nfs-server.service` to block the start of `nfs-server.service` even if some other service requires it.

Use first `systemctl unmask nfs-server.service` to unblock it, then `systemctl start nfs-server.service` to start it and `systemctl enable nfs-server.service` to make sure it will start automatically at boot time from this time onwards.

Note that `nfs-server.service` has dependencies on other services like `nfs-config.service`, `nfs-mountd.service`, `rpc-statd.service`, `nfs-idmapd.service`, `auth-rpcgss-module.service` and `rpc-statd-notify.service`.

Most of these services should start automatically once `nfs-server.service` is started, but if someone has masked some or all of these services, you might have to unmask these too.

Any services masked by an administrator should be identifiable with `ls -l /etc/systemd/system`: if you see a symbolic link with the name of a service, pointing to `/dev/null`, then that service is masked by an administrator command. For example, if `nfs-server.service` is masked, you will see a link with `nfs-server.service -> /dev/null`.

`/lib/systemd/system/nfs-common.service` is used in Debian/Ubuntu: in modern versions, it only exists to block the old SysVinit-style `/etc/init.d/nfs-common` script from executing unless you uninstall `systemd` and replace it with another init system package, since Debian now has individual `.service` files for each NFS component service for use with `systemd`, just like RHEL/CentOS does.